# How to display objects grouped by foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm a django n00b and am lost on how to do this.

sample models:

```
class Food_Type(models.Model):  
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)  

class Food(models.Model):  
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)  
  food_type = models.ForeignKey(Food_Type)
```

And some data:

```
v = Food_Type(name='Veggie')   
f = Food_Type(name='Fruit')  

c = Food(food_type=v, name='carrot')  
a = Food(food_type=f, name='apple')
```

The HTML output should look something like this:

**Veggie**
carrot

**Fruit**
apple

---

- I'm uncertain of the right way to do the grouping, I assume the view and not the template.

  ```
  food_type_list = Food_Type.objects.all().order_by('name')  
  food_list = []  
  for ft in food_type_list:  
      food_list.append(Food.objects.filter(fruit_type__exact=device_type.id)
  render_to_response(some_template,
    {'food_type': food_type_list, 'foods': food_list}
  )
  ```
- based on my view, I'm uncertain how to display

*Does not work and there has got to be a better way*

```
{% for type in food_type %}
  {{ type }}
  {% for food in foods %}
    {% if food.food_type == type %}
      {{ food.name }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [**`regroup`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

```
food = Food.objects.all()

{% regroup food by food_type as food_list %}

<ul>
{% for food_type in food_list %}
    <li>{{ food_type.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in food_type.list %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
Food.objects.order_by('food_type__name')
```

Comment: @bradley-ayers, I corrected my question.  I had some trouble with the submission form.  Now the question displays correctly.  order_by will sort the query results, but I need separate result sets based on the food_type.

Comment: Have a look at the `ifchanged` templatetag http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged